# React: Get Object within Navigation Options

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to get an object by reference string within the `ReactNavigation` `headerRight` section, however, it appears as though I am not getting the right instance of the main class as running the below code yields an "undefined is not an object."

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return <PrimaryNavigator/>;
  }
}

export const PrimaryNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Primary: {
    screen: Primary,
  }
});

export default class Primary extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Title',
    headerRight: <Text>{this.ref1.accessible}</Text>
  };

  return (
    <View ref="ref1">
    </View>
   );
  }
}
```

How should I access the object with reference "ref1" within the `navigationOptions` section?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because you're trying to access an instance variable inside a static function. You'd have to rethink the way you configure your navigation options. For example, you could pass props to the `PrimaryNavigator` and set `navigationOptions` where you create the `StackNavigator` right after the screen.